# Please resolve my problem of the package in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, installation, package, composer-php

The "ocramius/package-versions" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("^1.0.0") that does not match your Composer installation ("2.0.0"). You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins" option.

Comment: my code did run because of this

Comment: and you tried to run `composer update --no-plugins`?

Comment: i tried but code not running showing error  Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\mykitchenkart\kitchenkartapi/public/index.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\mykitchenkart\kitchenkartapi\server.php on line 21

Comment: Try `composer self-update 1.8.0` to change to a compatible composer version.

Comment: Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires mehedi-iitdu/core-component-repository dev-master -> satisfiable by mehedi-iitdu/core-component-repository[dev-master].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.1 (conflict analysis result)

Comment: try run `composer global update` as this user did and solve the same problem: https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/8320#issuecomment-717089800

Comment: The "ocramius/package-versions" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("^1.0.0") that does not match your Composer installation ("2.0.0"). You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins" option.
Upgrading to version 1.8.0 (stable channel).

Comment: Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\mykitchenkart\kitchenkartapi/public/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\mykitchenkart\kitchenkartapi\server.php on line 21

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\mykitchenkart\kitchenkartapi/public/index.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\mykitchenkart\kitchenkartapi\server.php on line 21

Comment: Please add **all clarification** to your question by editing it